# PCB Crystal layout for DSPIC33EP512MU810-E/BG

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, oscillator, crystal

I'm designing a PCB with 8MHz crystal for DSPIC33EP512MU810-E/BG (https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/DSPIC33EP512MU810-E-BG/DSPIC33EP512MU810-E-BG-ND/2765491)

On the datasheet, recommendations say that my traces should not exceed 12mm but this is the best I can do since my PCB board is defined and can't be changed.The crystal is side by side with the uC.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a ground plane below the crystal and the GND polygon pour around the crystal is 7mil.

[image].

Do you guys see any issue with this Crystal layout ?

Thanks,

Comment: Mount the package underneath.

Comment: Datasheet recommend not to.

Comment: What data sheet was that?

Comment: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70616g.pdf - p33

Comment: Rotate the MCU 90 degrees?

Comment: Not possible, with all the traces I am passing from the other side.

Comment: How long are the traces then? How about a smaller crystal so wiring is shorter?

Comment: 13.13
11.8
I tried smaller one and didn't approve the trace length ao much.

Comment: I'd place it underneath.

Comment: OP removed all the images, not sure why. Reverted the change.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use an XO to get an accurate reliable clock that does not have those issues.cheap.

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/crystals-oscillators-resonators/oscillators/172?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1989=0&pv2150=u8MHz&sf=1&FV=-8%7C172&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=300

If you use lots they also have programmable XO’s any tolerance

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it's probably okay, trace length is not that much greater than the recommendation.

Of course you're on your own even more than usual if it doesn't work under some conditions.